# How do I find what RPM package provides a system executable with Fedora?

Tags: fedora, rpm

Want package provides `gnome-sound-recorder` in Fedora?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pass `-f` when querying the rpmdb to specify a file to look for.

```
rpm -qf /path/to/executable
rpm -qf $(which executable)
```

If the file is not installed then ask `yum`.

```
yum whatprovides '*bin/executable'
```